# Keyboard Type "th" twice when typing "the"

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, typing

When I attempt to type the word "the", my keyboard gives me "ththe".

Note this does not happen when I type "this" or "that" or "th" by itself. Nor does "te", "et","eh", "he".

The "th" only repeats itself when "th" is used in combination with "e".

From further testing, typing "eth" will give me "etth" sometimes. Similarly, "eht" would show as "ehht".

Another note is that my laptop keyboard works fine with no issue.

What is the problem here? OS, Driver, keyboard? I did lower my repeat rate, which did nothing. In any case, repeat rate should not affect ththe duplication of "th".

I am using Unicomp keyboard(IBM model M copy with USB) with Dvorak layout  on Windows 7. PC model is HP Pavilion m6.

---

EDIT: chrome, word, firefox, eclipse, cmd, vim all do the same thing, So I think it's a system wide issue.

---

EDIT2: I switched my unicomp keyboard to us layout and tried to type "kjd" (which is equivalent of "the" in dvorak) it still repeats. I plugged in another Dell Keyboard, it worked fine. Curiously, when I plug my keyboard into this particular USB port (I have 4), the issue went away. However My mouse does not work on the other three ports either...do I have a usb problem?

---

Update: I have tried uninstalling Hub driver and restart. Also tried to take battery out leave overnight but is not working. I will try live the live CD boot soon.

Currently I am using a USB port expander from my only good USB port...

Comment: Is this in every program or just a single one?  Sounds like your auto correct settings have been changed...

Comment: chrome, word, firefox and vim all do thhte same thing, So I guess it's a system wide issue. how would I be checking ththe auto correct settings?

Comment: Ah, so this only happens with an external keyboard, not the one built into the laptop.  Can you try a different external keyboard?  It may be driver issues.

Comment: I could see that the Dvorak layout is conflicting with keyboard code that is attempting to disambiguate characters that are struck nearly simultaneously.  Likely has something to do with two keys being right next to each other.

Comment: I switched my unicomp keyboard to us layout and tried to type "kjd" (which is equivalent of "the" in dvorak) it still repeats. I plugged in another Dell Keyboard, it worked fine. Curiously, when I plug my keyboard into this particular USB port (I have 4), the issue went away. However My mouse does not work on the other three ports either...do I have a usb problem?

Comment: This is the most bizarre problem I've heard of in a while...

Comment: Pretty weird. It's not auto-complete if it follows keypresses instead of characters. Sounds like it's drivers or hardware. Are there any custom keyboard drivers involved - there must be something for the dvorak layout. Any you can update or uninstall? A mouse should work on any port. Usually ports in different physical locations have their own usb hub. Maybe a hub is bad. I don't use Windows much, so I don't know how to poke any deeper. If you know Linux at all, you might try booting from a live CD. If the problem goes away, then it's probably not hardware.